# What is the purpose of a triple pointer for 2d array?

Tags: c, pointers

```
                 // Triple Pointer Version       
     void init(char ***subjects_array, char***courses_array)
 {


     int i;

    *subjects_array = (char**) malloc (100 * sizeof(char*));
    *courses_array = (char**) malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));


    for(i = 0; i < INITIAL_COURSE_SIZE; i++)
   {
     (*subjects)[i] = (char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
     (*courses)[i] = (char*) malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
   } 


  }  // end of Triple pointer version


                       //  Double Pointer Version
          void init(char** subject_array, char** courses_array) {                   

  subject_array = (char **) malloc (100*sizeof(char*));
  courses_array = (char **) malloc (100*sizeof(char*));

 for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
    subject_array[i] = (char*) malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    courses_array[i] = (char*) malloc (6*sizeof(char));
   }
   }
```

My question is: Both versions initiate a 2d array. So what purpose does the triple pointer version serve? It seems that the extra level of indirection serves no "purpose".

Comment: Triple pointer version allows me to allocate and assign double pointers. But in this case, I don't see double pointers anywhere ? Could someone point it out?

Comment: There is no 2D array. You have an array of pointers to (array of) `char`. Standard warning: Casting the result of `malloc` in C is discouraged! C is not C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C passes parameters, including pointers, only by value, you need to add an extra level of indirection (i.e. an asterisk) for any parameter that you wish to modify inside a function.

This provides the clue to what's going on: normally, you need two asterisks for a 2D array, i.e. `char **twoD`. However, since `init` allocates a new array, you need an extra level of indirection, i.e.

```
void init(char ***subjects_array, char***courses_array)
```

and also passing pointers to your 2D arrays from the caller:

```
char **subj, **courses;
init(&subj, &courses);
```

That is also the reason why the parameters are dereferenced inside `init`:

```
*subjects_array = (char**) malloc (100 * sizeof(char**));
//                                                  ^
//                                                  |
//       An asterisk was missing here --------------+
```

the asterisk in front of `subjects_array` tells the compiler to make an assignment through the pointer, modifying the variable passed into `init` by the caller.

Comment: Hi. Could you explain more of this part: "However, since init allocates a new array, you need an extra level of indirection".                                       The double pointer version init also allocates a new array, but without the extra level of indirection. Does that mean the double pointer version's allocation is not saved once it leaves the local function?

Comment: @JackW If you pass a double-pointer into the function, the function will be able to allocate a single-pointer array. If you pass a triple-pointer, you would be able to allocate and assign a double-pointer, and so on. Since 2D array is a double pointer, assigning it requires a triple pointer.

Comment: I understand. But according to the triple pointer version. I'm only allocating single char pointers. In which part of the code did I allocate and assign a double pointer? I'm very confused. thanks

Comment: @JackW Ah, I see. Your code was indeed missing an asterisk. It's usually one of these UBs that never gets caught, because sizes of double and triple pointers are almost always the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help!